# Perl and Regex - single line mode matching

Tags: regex, string, perl, whitespace

Why doesn't

```
perl -ne "print if /(<Conn)([\S|\s]+?)(>)/sg;" /path/to/file
```

match

```
<Connector port="PORT" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />`
```

when it does match

```
<Connector port="PORT" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="PORT" />
```

And what would I need to do to match both with the same regex?

Comment: Because it search line by line.

Comment: Also, what would I need to do to match both with the same regex?

Comment: Because you are running the regex linewise instead of for the whole file by using the '-n' flag.

Comment: Note that the `s` modifier makes `.` match a newline; even if you were processing more than one line at a time, the `s` wouldn't do anything since your regex contains no `.`s.

Comment: Tip: By `[\S|\s]`, you probably meant `[\S\s]`, which is the same thing as `.` when `/s` is used.

Comment: Tip: `if /.../g` makes no sense, and the results of this bug are subtle. That should be `if /.../` or `while /.../g`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-n` option reads the file line-by-line, but you can alter what a line is to be the whole file by undefining the input line terminator. That's is done using `local $/;`, or using the command line option `-0777` as follows:

```
perl -0777ne 'print "$1\n" while /(<Conn.+?>)/sg;' /path/to/file
```

It reads in the whole file at once.  If that's a problem, try setting `$/` to `>` (since your pattern always ends in `>`) or `-o076` on the command-line:

```
perl -076ne 'print "$1\n" if /(<Conn.+?>)/sg;' /path/to/file
```

Comment: Or `perl -0777 -ne ...`

Comment: Both of those print out the entire file, most of which does not match the regex

Comment: @kjpires

That's awesome and almost works, it only matches the first instance of such. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Chris Hines, `perl -0777nle'print $1 while /(<Conn.+?>)/sg;' /path/to/file`

Answer (score 0):

Because it is running line-wise. On your first data, $_ will take on three separate values

1. ```
   <Connector port="PORT" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
   ```
2. ```
   maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
   ```
3. ```
   clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
   ```

and none of these will match on their own.

If you want to make it match, perhaps you could try slurping the whole file.

```
my $whole_file = do { local $/; <> };
```